# websockets.exceptions.ConnectionClosedError: code = 1011 (unexpected error), no reason

Tags: python, websocket

The server close connection for the client after a while and client disconnect automatically after try to send a message :

```
    newmsg = await websocket.recv()
```

Answer (score 13):

the problem is the server is sending pings to the client and try to get a response which is the newmsg, when the msg is not sent back then the server close the connection after 20 sec which is the default value, the solution is to desactivate the ping from the server and the client if you want :
server.py:

```
start_server = websockets.serve(receive_name, "localhost", 8765,ping_interval=None)
```

client.py :

```
    async with websockets.connect(uri, ping_interval=None) as websocket:
```

Comment: I tried deactivating the ping from the client (I guess the only option as I don't run the server) and seems to work, but is there any downside from doing this? (thinking of a program that would be continuously downloading data if not closed). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is not from your client side's code. Mine is from server side because of a typo. Should also check the server side's log and see if there is any error.

Answer (score 0):

Mine case was handling wrong key by server side.

Server expected:

```json
{
    "data": 1,
    "build_id": 43
}
```

but i send:

```json
{
    "data": 1,
    "build": 43
}
```

so it can not handle `build` key and error code was `1011` without reason.

Answer (score 0):

The issue most probably is a blocking code somewhere like user input with:

```
inp = input("enter a message")
```

something like that, in either server code or client code, just figure it out and replace it with equivalent non blocking code, this blocking code is the reason of the blocking of internal ping, pong requests.. so this issue is coming.